# unnecessary space on left side in nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a space beetwin my nav link it about 2px and i cant remove it, is it anny css code that can do it?

When you hover over Downloads you can see the space on left side.

jsFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/asRz3/1/

HTML:

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head> 
    <!--- START Styles --->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--- END Styles --->
    <!--- START Scripts --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src"js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!--- END Scripts --->
</head>
<body>
    <!--- NavBar TOP --->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu">F.A.Q's</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Latest News</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Downloads</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Client Login</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-image: url('img/navbar-custom.png');
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.left-nav-space {
    height: 70px;
    width: 200px;   
}
.navbar-menu {
    height: 59px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    text-align: center; 
    border-right: 2px solid #282828;
    border-left: 2px solid #282828;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.navbar-menu:hover {
    background-image: url('img/navbar-menu-hover.png');
}
.navbar-menu2 {
    height: 59px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;   
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    text-align: center; 
    border-right: 2px solid #282828;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.navbar-menu2:hover {
    background-image: url('img/navbar-menu-hover.png');

}
```

Comment: Which gap are you talking about?

Comment: When you hover over Downloads you can see the space on left side. jsFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/asRz3/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `display: inline-block;` so use `margin-left: -4px;` for `.navbar-menu2`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/asRz3/7/)

```
.navbar-menu2 {
    margin-left: -4px;
    /* Other Styles */
}
```

Because when you use `display: inline-block;` it leaves a `4px` white space between the elements, to get over this, you need to use `margin-left: -4px;`

Comment: @user2736147 well, its fine if you are happy with a floating value hehe but I don't think 3.5 renders as 3.5, it renders as 4 :) and you welcome

Answer (score 2):

I've updated you fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/asRz3/8/

The thing is, you had whitespaces between your `a` in your html.
(new line is treated as whitespace in `inline-block` element)

you can fix is in numerous ways.

1. Remove all white spaces from your html (as I did in your fiddle)
2. Apply 'font-size: 0;' to the container (and then reaplly font size for each element who tries to write somthing)
3. Aplly negative margin (not recomended, because the space is deferrent between browsers)

Answer (score 1):

The gaps you see are caused by the newlines.

This is caused by inline `<a></a> <a></a>` spaces.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation"><a href="#" class="navbar-menu">F.A.Q's</a><a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Latest News</a><a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Downloads</a><a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Client Login</a><a href="#" class="navbar-menu2">Contact Us</a></nav>
```

Its ugly that way though. Use floats I guess?

http://jsfiddle.net/asRz3/12/

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue when using inline-block.
Remove spaces between li in html like so:

```
<ul>

<li> 
<a href="#">Link here.</a> 
</li><li> 
<a href="#">Link here.</a> 
</li><li> 
<a href="#">Link here.</a> 
</li>

</ul>
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexlime/asRz3/5/)
and here is [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) article you can read about this known problem

Answer (score -1):

You can remove

```
padding-left: 10px;
```

from the css

Comment: That did only move the text.